# How do I enable OpenGL 3.3 on Fedora 23 with AMD graphics card?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, fedora, amd-radeon

I am using the open-source Mesa drivers (Gallium3D/radeonsi), which should support OpenGL 3.3, but don't seem to on my system.

According to [this news article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?px=MTU4NjI&page=news_item) and [this page](http://mesamatrix.net/) recent Mesa versions should support OpenGL 3.3, but when I query for the OpenGL support on my system, I only see 3.0 supported:

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"                                    
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.4 (git-ec14e6f)
```

I am using Fedora 23 with xorg-x11-drv-ati.x86_64 7.6.0-0.4.20150729git5510cd6.fc23 and [these mesa packages](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/292300/79413201/). My graphics card is a Asus Radeon R9 280X DirectCU 2 TOP

So for me it seems like that something went wrong with the configuration, because theoretically it should be supported

Comment: The version of OpenGL supported is hardware dependent.

Comment: _"My graphics card is a Asus Radeon R9 280X DirectCU 2 TOP_" and that graphics card supports OpenGL 3.3